# log all queries that mongoose fire in the application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have application using nodejs and mongodb. I have used mongoose for ODM. 
Now i want to log all the queries that mongoose fire during the whole application.

How to log these?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

You can enable debug mode like so:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

or add your own debug callback:

```
mongoose.set('debug', function (coll, method, query, doc [, options]) {
 //do your thing
});
```

This will log all executed collection methods and their arguments to the console.

Comment: how does mongoose format the log.  IE I would like to use the second option to let winston log.  I like the format mongoose logs and I would format my log w/ winston the same way.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the following format:

```
mongoose.set("debug", (collectionName, method, query, doc) => {
    console.log(`${collectionName}.${method}`, JSON.stringify(query), doc);
});
```

or any other logger of your choice:

```
mongoose.set("debug", (collectionName, method, query, doc) => {
    logger(`${collectionName}.${method}`, JSON.stringify(query), doc);
});
```

Comment: Nice. But how to add color to only value like mongoose debug default

Comment: you can use chalk npm module to color, whichever values you want to colorize
`log(\`
CPU: ${chalk.red('90%')}
RAM: ${chalk.green('40%')}
DISK: ${chalk.yellow('70%')}
\`);`

Answer (score 12):

I'm using node bunyan, this is an option to debug and track queries(may help someone else)

```
function serializer(data) {
    let query = JSON.stringify(data.query);
    let options = JSON.stringify(data.options || {});

    return `db.${data.coll}.${data.method}(${query}, ${options});`;
}

let log = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'AppName',
    src: false,
    serializers: {
        // ...
        dbQuery: querySerializer
        // ...
    },
    // ...
});

mongoose.set('debug', function(coll, method, query, doc, options) {
    let set = {
        coll: coll,
        method: method,
        query: query,
        doc: doc,
        options: options
    };

    log.info({
        dbQuery: set
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to log filename and line number from where the query is executed. Is there anyway i can do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can also set debug logger parameters:

```
node index.js DEBUG=mquery
```

but this will only log *queries*, not insert or update statements.