# Where`s log responses mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

Is there a log by default? I did not have any data in the database, so I need to find the queries that were handling the Mongoose. The debugging mode was enabled.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762264/log-all-queries-that-mongoose-fire-in-the-application) SO question?

Comment: Google translate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log all queries that mongoose fire in the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762264/log-all-queries-that-mongoose-fire-in-the-application)

Comment: Requests to the console are displayed. Are they recorded somewhere?