# How do I count the documents that include a value within an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a Mongoose `abTest` document that has two fields:

1. `status`. This is a string enum and can be of type `active`, `inactive` or `draft`.
2. `validCountryCodes`. This is an array of strings enums (`GB`, `EU`, `AU` etc). By default, it will be empty.

In the DB, at any one time, I only want there to be one active `abTest` for each `validCountryCode` so I'm performing some validation prior to creating or editing a new `abTest`.

To do this, I've written a function that attempts to count the number of documents that have a `status` of `active` and that contain one of the `countryCodes`.

The function will then return if the count is more than one. If so, I will throw a validation error.

```js
if (params.status === 'active') {
  const activeTestForCountryExists = await checkIfActiveAbTestForCountry(
    validCountryCodes,
  );
  if (params.activeTestForCountryExists) {
    throw new ValidationError({
      message: 'There can only be one active test for each country code.',
    });
  }
}

const abTest = await AbTest.create(params);
```

`checkIfActiveAbTestForCountry()` looks like this:

```js
const checkIfActiveAbTestForCountry = async countryCodes => {
  const query = {
    status: 'active',
  };

  if (
    !countryCodes ||
    (Array.isArray(countryCodes) && countryCodes.length === 0)
  ) {
    query.validCountryCodes = {
      $eq: [],
    };
  } else {
    query.validCountryCodes = { $in: [countryCodes] };
  }

  const count = await AbTest.countDocuments(query);
  return count > 0;
};
```

The count query should count not only exact array matches, but for any partial matches.

If in the DB there is an `active` `abTest` with a `validCountryCodes` array of `['GB', 'AU',]`, the attempting to create a new `abTest` with `['GB'` should fail. As there is already a test with `GB` as a `validCountryCode`.

Similarly, if there is a test with a `validCountryCodes` array of `['AU']`, then creating a test with `validCountryCodes` of `['AU,'NZ']` should also fail.

Neither is enforced right now.

How can I do this? Is this possible write a query that checks for this?

I considered iterating over `params.validCountryCodes` and counting the docs that include each, but this seems like bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this MongoDB [documantation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/).

As I understood what you need is to find out if there is any document that contains at least one of the specified `countryCodes` and it has `active` status. then your query should look like this:

```js
{ 
  status: 'active',
  $or: [
    { validCountryCodes: countryCodes[0] },
    { validCountryCodes: countryCodes[1] },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

note that counting documents is not an efficient manner to check if a document exists or not, instead use `findOne` with only one field being projected.

Comment: If I do this then a document with a `validCountryCodes` of `['AU','GB']` won't match `['GB']`. It should!

Comment: if you have a document like this: `{status: 'active', validCountryCodes: ['AU','GB']}` it will match this query `{ status: 'active', validCountryCodes: 'GB' }`

`

Comment: True! But the argument coming in through `checkIfActiveAbTestForCountry` is an array of `countryCodes`, so I'm essentially looking to count the documents in which there are at least one common element

Comment: @judgejab I have updated the answer, you can use a loop to build the `$or` array

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct mongo-query for your requirement. Can you verify the actual queries executed from your application is the same? Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762264/log-all-queries-that-mongoose-fire-in-the-application)

```
{ status: 'active', validCountryCodes: { $in: [ countryCodes ] } }
```

For eg; below query :

```
{ status: 'active', validCountryCodes: { $in: ['GB' ] } }
```

should match document :

```
{ status: 'active', validCountryCodes: ['AU','GB'] }
```