# Product.find() is taking forever, not returning any output

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, next.js

It is supposed to return empty object of product but it is retuning nothing just loading forever and ever, I have checked through code, checked every possibility of code returning an  error or something but couldn't figure out anything. I've been stuck at this from last two days, finally decided to post it here. someone please help.

Here is my mongoose.js file

```
const mongoURI="mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const connectDb=handler=>async(req,res)=>{
    if(mongoose.connections[0].readyState){ 
        return handler(req,res);
    }
        mongoose.connect(mongoURI,()=>{ 
            console.log("connect to mongo successfully");
        }); 
    return handler(req,res);
}
export default connectDb;
```

Here is my Product.js file

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  


const ProductSchema= new Schema({
    title:{type:String,required:true},
    slug:{type:String,required:true,unique:true},
    desc:{type:String,required:true},
    img:{type:String,required:true},
    category:{type:String,required:true},
    size:{type:String},
    color:{type:String},
    price:{type:Number,required:true},
    availbleQty:{type:Number,required:true},

}, {timestamps:true}); 

 
module.exports = mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

Here is my getproducts.js file

```
import connectDb from "../../middleware/mongoose" 
  
const handler=async (req,res)=>{
    let products=await Product.find(); 
    res.status(200).json({products})
}
export default connectDb(handler);
```

The console is :

```
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 521 ms (1261 modules)
connect to mongo successfully
```

Comment: Try enabling debug logging for Mongoose to observe what happens between receiving the query and returning the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762264/log-all-queries-that-mongoose-fire-in-the-application

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add the query in a try/catch block. Moreover try to add a return statement:

```
 const handler=async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        let products=await Product.find(); 
        return res.status(200).json({products})
     }catch(err){
     console.log(err)
     return res.status(500)
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 and it worked. Don't know why this is a thing but yeah it's working now.